# Replacing headliner in honda accord 2008

Tags: interior

I have a honda accord, the foam failed (not the adhesive in the foam) and is pulling apart. The fabric is fine. I have some good adhesives to glue the foam back to the ceiling of the car, but I've heard the foam is good to reduce noise. Is there any way to replace the foam between the headliner and the fabric?

Comment: It may be possible but I suspect it will be quite difficult.  If I'm not mistaken, the foam is also glued to the fabric so to get it off you'll have to do a lot of scraping and will likely damage the fabric.  It might be simpler, easier, and overall less expensive to just get a new headliner and replace the entire thing.

Comment: You can easily get new headliner material from most fabric stores. It is fabric with the foam backing. There's a question on here already about how to replace the headliner material.

Comment: @jwh20 I already got the old foam off.